# Different UserType for different database in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, h2

I'm developing an application in Spring Boot and Hibernate. I've created a class implementing `UserType`, which maps `java.time.Duration` to `INTERVAL` in PostgreSQL. Using it in following manner:

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(typeClass = DurationUserType.class, defaultForType = Duration.class)
}
```

works fine.

I'm running unit tests with H2. Since it doesn't support `INTERVAL` type, Hibernate fails at initialization with H2. I'm looking for the way to somehow associate `DurationUserType` with PostgreSQL dialect, so this it's not used in unit tests.